# embed config file in excel xlsm

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010, ribbonx

I was wondering if anyone has embedded a small config (csv essentially) file inside an xlsm and read from/written to it to save settings. Currently I use an external config file and Windows ini API function to access the info.

I've been looking on the internet and haven't found anything of use.  Most it refers to embedding a spreadsheet in a web page or embedding a gallery in the spreadsheet.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: "Custom XML Parts" may be of use (if you can use xml rather than csv) eg [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608618.aspx)